# Optional Package UWP not able to reference code from Optional Package?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create a UWP project (C# XAML UWP) where I can consume an Optional Package (also C# XAML UWP). I created a sample where I followed the documentation here: [Optional Package Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages-with-executable-code#c-optional-packages-with-executable-code-1). However after I reference the winmd file from the reference folder and deploy I get a Class Not registered exception. Any help or knowledge on how to do this is apreciated.

Thanks,

Daniel Breaux

Comment: I was able to use related sets to get a bit of a working solution. Linking my Microsoft Forums Question just in case it helps someone [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/974633/optional-packages-uwp-c.html)

Comment: But now Im trying to figure out how to do this without related sets so that I dont have to have the package and Main App tightly coupled. I want to be able to deploy the optional package and have changes that dont require a recompile of the main app. And Related sets would force me to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: More or less the answer I found was that I needed to make it a related set and then I had some difficulties interacting because its treated as a Win RT Component project so I've had to revise the architecture but the documentation was correct.

Answer (score 0):

> However after I reference the winmd file from the reference folder and deploy I get a Class Not registered exception.

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/optional-packages-with-executable-code#c-optional-packages-with-executable-code-1) going to setp 9, In the main app project, navigate to the project build properties and select **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**. Go to the main project debug properties and select  **Deploy optional packages**.

[image]